Rotation of moving prefabs
I'm creating a game where as a player you need to dodge objects which are moving downwards. I have objects moving on the right and left side of the screen.
By default my prefab is created to spawn on the right side and face right, and I need to mirror this prefab onto the left side correctly.
I instantiate prefabs and apply force to them to move downwards:
// SpawnManager.cs
Instantiate(obstaclePrefabs, spawnPosLeft, transform.rotation);

// MoveDown.cs
void Update()
{
    if (playerPositionScript.gameOver == false)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

I've tried:

Changing prefab rotation:

Instantiate(obstaclePrefabs, spawnPosLeft, transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180));


Adding an empty gameObject inside my prefab and trying to rotate it:

 public GameObject obstaclePrefabs;
 private GameObject obstacleRotation;

void Start()
{
 obstacleRotation = obstaclePrefabs.GetComponentInChildren<GameObject>();
 InvokeRepeating("SpawnRandomObstacle", 0, delaySpawn); 
}

private void SpawnRandomObstacle()
{
obstacleRotation.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180);
Instantiate(obstaclePrefabs, spawnPosLeft, transform.rotation);
}

What went wrong:

It wasn't correct because I'm constantly applying force from top to bottom and when I rotate an object it goes from bottom to top.
It just can't find my empty gameObject inside of the obstaclePrefab and nothing spawns.


Instantiate(obstaclePrefabs, spawnPosLeft, Quaternion.identity).transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);

This code snippet instantiates the prefab at spawnPosLeft with no rotation (Quaternion.identity) and then immediately flips the prefab's scale on the x-axis to -1, effectively mirroring it.
